# How to implement show and hide fragment inside fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

How to implement show and hide fragment inside fragment in Android? I have added two fragment inside activity. One fragment containing menu and one fragment contain sub menu. I have lot of button in menu fragment like home, idea, etc. If i click idea button. I have to show sub menu. If I again click idea button, I have to hide the sub menu. Can anybody provide example, or how to access one view fragment in another fragment?

this is my layout main

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<fragment class="com.gcm.fragment.CommonFragment"
            android:id="@+id/the_frag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />  
 <fragment class="com.gcm.fragment.SubFragment"
            android:id="@+id/the_frag1"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />             


</LinearLayout>
```

In My fragment

```
package com.gcm.fragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CommonFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    TextView txtIhaveIdea=null;
  boolean menuVisible=false;
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.collapsed_menu2, container, false); 

        txtIhaveIdea=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.txtIhaveAnIdea);
        txtIhaveIdea.setOnClickListener(this);

        return layout; 
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(!menuVisible)
        {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); 
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction(); 
        fm.beginTransaction(); 
        Fragment fragOne = new SubFragment(); 
        ft.show(fragOne);
        }
        else
        {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); 
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction(); 

            fm.beginTransaction(); 
            Fragment fragOne = new SubFragment(); 
            ft.hide(fragOne);   
        }

    } 



}
```

Thanks

Comment: Refer to reference code for fragments hide/show given on android site http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentHideShow.html

Comment: @kumar did u achieved ur task?

Answer (score 5):

You could try get framelayout or fragment by id and change its visibility

```
View frag = findViewById(R.id.my_fragment);
frag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 5):

Considering this question has over 2K .. an answer may still help new readers so here it goes:

- You don't really want to have FragmentManager and FragmentTransactions happening inside fragments not to have Casts nor potential harmful references to your Activity(s)

So what I do and works just fine is set an interface to the Fragment and give a method, say needsHide():

```
public class MyFrag extends Fragment {

public interface MyFragInterface {

    public void needsHide();
}
```

Then implement it on your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MyFrag.MyFragInterface {
public void needsHide() {

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    //find the fragment by View or Tag
    MyFrag myFrag = (MyFrag)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(SOME_TAG);
    fragmentTransaction.hide(myFrag);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
        //do more if you must
}}
```

The only part that requires thought is when to call  needsHide(), this you might do in your Fragment's onViewCreated, since you are sure that it's not too early for your MainActivity to commit transactions. If you place it onCreate() it may not work depending on what you do with oter fragments:

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Making sure Main activity implemented interface
    try {
        if (USE_A_CONDITION) {
            ((MyFragInterface)this.getActivity()).needsHide();
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Calling activity must implement MyFragInterface");
    }
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply, create a public method in your "parent" activity. which hides the fragment.

Then from within the fragment in your click event get the "parent|' activity, cast it and then call the method you created.

```
    ((ParentActitity)getActivity()).hideFragment();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an Interface to communicate with your parent Activity.

Take a look on Vogella's tutorial, "3.4. Application communication with Fragments". Here is the [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

method `hide()`:Hides an existing fragment.  This is only relevant for fragments whose views have been added to a container, as this will cause the view to be hidden.

your code :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(!menuVisible)
    {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); 
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction(); 
    fm.beginTransaction(); 
    Fragment fragOne = new SubFragment(); 
    ft.show(fragOne);
    }
    else
    {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); 
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction(); 

        fm.beginTransaction(); 
        // it's wrong , you just hide the fragment that not added to  FragmentTransaction
        Fragment fragOne = new SubFragment(); 
        ft.hide(fragOne);   
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code worked for me..

```
View frag = findViewById(R.id.fragment);
frag.setVisibility(View.GONE);//Or View.INVISBLE
```